# how to purge python 3.3 and install python 2.7.4

Tags: python3

I'm in complete trouble with my Ubuntu 13.04 distro. Today I wanted to try python 3.3, I compiled it and installed from source. It broke my system,  many packages wait for apt-get remove cmmand. I tried to purge python by issuing "sudo apt-get remove –purge python*" after then I still can  not revert to python 2.7.4.  Most importantly how can I reinstall my system? I feel like hanging in gallow, please help.

Comment: That version of Ubuntu already has Python 3.3, meaning you could have simply installed it via `apt-get`. Anyways, can you show what error messages you get... the ones that convinced you you can't revert to `2.7.4`?

Comment: It was a known bug with python 2.7.4. The error message was "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py'" 
Here is the filed bug : http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=709157#

Comment: I know 13.04 has python3.3 but mine was using python2.7.4. Upgrading to 3.3 borked my system

Comment: same problem with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed uninstallation problem by putting back "sitecustomize.py" It was deleted during upgrading to python3.3 so I could not purge python. I searched for it by "locate sitecustomize.py" luckily I found it in remastersys folder. I copied it into `sudo cp /home/remastersys/remastersys/dummysys/etc/python2.7/sitecustomize.py /usr/lib/python2.7/` then ran `sudo dpkg -a --configure` uninstallation problem fixed. Thank you Tshepang for answer

**Edit:** Today after system updated  python, I met the `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py’` error again.
I navigated using `cd /usr/lib/python2.7/`  then executed `ls`.

to my surprize "sitecustomize.py" was in the list in red. I think it was a symlink and main   file was deleted during update. So I removed symlink and copied main file I found in "/home/remastersys/remastersys/dummysys/etc/python2.7/sitecustomize.py" into " /usr/lib/python2.7/" then ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Problem fixed.